# Arrange nested layouts in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scroll

I want to create a layout that looks like this:

[image]

So a few different categories and in each of that, 4 elements should be positioned.

I have tried to make a `ScrollView` first (because it should be possible to scroll) and then having vertical and horizontal `LinearLayouts` nested into each other. But it doesn't work.

I don't want to use the `GridLayout` because this requires API 14 and higher, and my app should work for the API 10 or lower.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Include Android support libraries maybe ?

Comment: @BrigitteFellner it would be appreciated to accept the answer that was prompt and most useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an example of a type of custom `ListView`.So instead of what you are doing now, try creating a custom adapter for adding labels and buttons to each of your row items within the list as per your needs you have given in your diagram link.

Learn more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)